# Get the count of number of committed records in mule batch commit

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am using batch processing to update the records in DB. Batch commit size is 100.  My batch flow looks like below

```
  <batch:process-records>
           <batch:step name="Batch_Step" >
                <batch:commit doc:name="Batch Commit" size="100">
                    <db:update config-ref="DB_Configuration"bulkMode="true"  doc:name="Update" target="#[flowVars.count]">
                        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[update student set
                         column1=value1,
                         column2=value2 where id > 2000;] > </db:parameterized-query></db:update></batch:commit> </batch:step> </batch:process-records>
```

How can i get the number of records updated in each batch commit? I was expecting the flowVars.count in the target will have that count. But when i print i dont see the count. How can i get the number of records committed successfully?

Comment: Do you need stats on successful records after each batch commit or after after all batch commits have been committed?

Comment: I am looking for how many records were successfully updated in each batch and after all batch commits both. For example: i have 20000 records, in first batch there can be 80 records eligible for update because my where condition is id > 2000, in second batch there can be 50 records and so on ...so after all batch commits were done, the total number of updates were say 12000 records. How can i get this count?

Answer (score 0):

On complete state tells you `overall status` of the successful, failure records.

Batch have its own batch flow Variable called `<batch:record-variable-transformer doc:name="Record Variable"/>`normal flowVars dont work inside Batch.

If you want to process the failure record separately use one more batch step and mark `accept-policy="ONLY_FAILURES"`, so whatever the record failed in batch step 'Allow only Success' will go to the `handle failure' flow

```
     <batch:job name="sample_projectBatch" max-failed-records="-1">
    <batch:process-records>
        <batch:step name="Allow only Success " accept-policy="NO_FAILURES">
            <batch:record-variable-transformer doc:name="Record Variable"/>
        </batch:step>
        <batch:step name="handle failure" accept-policy="ONLY_FAILURES">
            <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
         <!-- logic to handle the failure -->
        </batch:step>
    </batch:process-records>
</batch:job>
```

Comment: yes i am aware of accept-policies and record variables. how can i get the count for the example that i have given?

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more the "where id > 2000" condition in your query? Is "id" or "2000" coming from your payload?

If not then I don't understand how the query isn't just overwritting the same db records over and over again.

Comment: id is coming from payload

Comment: Then payload.id > 2000 doesn't need to be in the SQL query. If you filter the payload.id <= 2000 records out before the batch commit step then you'll be able to count them easily. u add an Accept Eexpression <batch:step name="adultsOnlyStep" accept-expression="#[payload.age > 21]">

Comment: Add an Accept Expression `<batch:step name="IdFilterStep" accept-expression="#[payload.id <= 2000]">` Then you could count the times you enter the step which holds the batch commit. 

..continued. Or use a Message Filter `<message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true" doc:name="idFilter">
            <expression-filter expression="#[payload.id <= 2000]""/>
        </message-filter>` then use the onComplete phase count variables.

Comment: hmm..i am aware of this..my use case is little different.Thanks for the suggestion.